# Aggregated time weekly, quarter, microsecond in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

If I want to aggregate data from `microseconds` to `year`

Is there any effective way to achieve this on `Ruby on Rails 4` with `PostgreSQL`

```
weekly
quarter
milliseonds
microseconds
every 7 minutes
```

Suppose I have 3 columns `timestamp(unit:nanoseconds) price volume`

The time is aggregated by the column `tick_time`

Comment: PostgreSQL relies on the underlying operating system for a lot of stuff, including the resolution of timestamps. The underlying OS might not support microsecond precision. Apart from that issue, one aggregate query is a lot like the next. What does "tick_time" mean, exactly?

Comment: Hi @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I updated it , it represents the timestamp for the record